# How to search for a string which is not followed by another string

Tags: windows, search, windows-explorer

I want to do a search on my file system using windows explorer.
The search must find all files containing the string `example`.

This can easily be done with the search `content:example`
However I want to filter out the hits with a specific string following the given string e.g. `example_content`.

I can't just not show the file if it contains `example_content` because the file might have `example` without the `_content` following somewhere in it.

I have tried to search like `content:example NOT content:example_content` and `content:example -content:example_content` but this doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this search on the windows explorer search bar?

Comment: Is it programming related question?

Comment: @VedPrakash no windows explorer related question